# KeyError ошибка

Tags: django

**Ошибка:**

```
KeyError at /goods/good/15/delete/
'good_id'
```

**Код:**

views.py

```
class GoodDelete(DeleteView, GoodEditMixin, GoodEditView):
    model = Good
    template_name = 'good_delete.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'good_id'
    # fields = ['name', 'description', 'price', 'in_stock', 'category']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.success_url = reverse('index', kwargs={'cat_id': Good.objects.get(pk=kwargs['good_id']).category.id})

        return super(GoodDelete, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GoodDelete, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['good'] = Good.objects.get(pk=kwargs['good_id'])
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^good/(?P<good_id>\d+)/$', GoodDetailView.as_view(), name='good'),
    url(r'^(?P<cat_id>\d+)/add/$', GoodCreate.as_view(), name='good_add'),
    url(r'^good/(?P<good_id>\d+)/edit/$', GoodUpdate.as_view(), name='good_edit'),
    url(r'^good/(?P<good_id>\d+)/delete/$', GoodDelete.as_view(), name='good_delete')
]
```

Comment: `good_id` не передается в контекст, судя по ошибке. Вообще тяжело помочь вопросу оформленному таким образом

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам получать объект через `Good.objects.get(pk=kwargs['good_id'])`, если у класса есть атрибут `object`.
Используйте просто:`self.object`.

Но если очень хочется, то вместо `kwargs['good_id']`, используйте `self.pk`.

1. Похоже что в книге опечатка.
   Строка должна выглядеть так:

`context['good'] = Good.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['good_id'])`

2. В данном примере метод `get_context_data` можно убрать из кода и ничего не поменяется. Говорю так, потому что сам делаю все по книге В. Дронов - Django - Практика создания web сайтов на python 2016